# Is there a way to use git push-option in intellij?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Is there a way in IntelliJ to specify the push-option parameter while doing a git push? I use GitLab CI and to skip the CI you could pass skip ci as a push-option parameter. As I don't see this feature in Intellij I have to put it in the commit message, but this means that for this exact commit I will never be able to run the CI process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the options are always the same, you could set them via the `push.pushOption` in git config and it will work when pushing from the IDE

There is a feature request for --push-option support, please vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202210

Comment: Hi, no they are not always the same, as it depends on if I want to execute the CI pipeline or not, but thank you for the link, I will vote.

Answer (score 2):

It is still not possible to specify the options.

But as a workaround for the GitLab CI case, you can instruct it to skip CI by adding a "command" to the commit message of the latest commit you are pushing:

```
$ git commit -m "Some information

[skip ci]
"

$ git push   # CI will not be triggered
```

However, this causes a bug if you are also using GitLab ChatOps integration with Slack slash commands: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/328790

Answer (score -1):

Intellij does not give the ability to add custom push options. But you can use this plugin that I developed for this reason: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/23413-git-custom-push

**Usage:**
After installing the plugin, you will have a new button "Push with options..." in the commit tool window and Git menu.
After commiting your changes, you can click on the new button "Push with options..." and then a dialog well appear with some predefined push options (checkboxes) and a text field if you want to add another custom option.

There are some predefined push options. For example: `-o ci.skip` to skip gitlab CI pipeline

[image]

Comment: Can I know the reason for the downvote and how is the answer is not useful?
The question is "Is there a way to use git push-option in intellij?" and I think the plugin does this

Comment: Please see [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), that will help answer your question. You properly disclosed your affiliation, which is good, but your answer relies on just a link to your plugin, without further instructions on how to use it to solve the specific problem.

Comment: This is a much improved answer—but you removed your affiliation. Please be sure to disclose that you are the author of this plugin.